# Does python have macros?

Tags: python, macros

I am wondering whether python has macros like C/C++, that will insert the code at the caller site instead of making a function call. One use case I have in mind is as follows

```
# In lib.py
def get_current_dir():
    return os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

# In app.py
current_dir = get_current_dir()
```

This does not work unless `get_current_dir` is a macro, i.e. it replace the `get_current_dir` call with the `os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))` inside the `app.py`. Because otherwise the returned directory will be the one `lib.py` lives in, which is not necessarily the same as `app.py` lives in.

Comment: Could you not pass `__file__` into `get_current_dir`?

Comment: @TankorSmash, in this simple example, yes. I'm interested in the more general question about whether it is possible to have a macro, which could be more complicated than `get_current_dir`.

Comment: To answer the question title: No, Python does not have macros.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there are no macros in Python. The only clean solution I see is to pass the argument to your function.

Answer (score -2):

Sort of. Look at the [`eval()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval) function and / or the [`exec`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-exec-statement) statement.

Comment: Those are nothing like C/C++ macros.